# xskak and null moves

Tags: xskak

Some annotators use "--" for a null-move in annotations, like:

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Test"]
[Black "Test"]
[Opening "?"]
[ECO "?"]
[Result "1-0"]

1. d4 (1. e4 -- 2. d4) *
```

However, xskak doesn't recognise that and prints ZZ (with a minus) if I just convert that line using

```
(\variation[level=2]{1. e4 -- 2. d4})
```

, because it doesn't recognise it. Is there a trick or a work-around to get the "--"?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% 
\usepackage{xskak} 
\begin{document} 
\newchessgame 
\mainline{1. d4} (\variation[level=2]{1. e4 -- 2. d4}) 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt it, but without a complete example I can't test.

Comment: OK :-) I added a minimal example. I'm close to finishing a python pgn2latex script that works for complex games.

Comment: Can you replace the -- with something else in your script?

Comment: sure, I just don't know what a clever replacement would look like :-) .

Comment: Well the easiest would be to split the variation `\variation{1. e4}  \variation{2. d4}`. All other ways looks nasty.

Comment: Yes, I could do that and just use xskakcomment to display "--" if I want to. Unfortunately, there is the problem that if a variation starts with a black null move, I want the move number in front and can't just replace the move. I guess I need to enter the "1..." with a comment then (which is possible, yet slightly ugly). Btw., thanks for your help, I was reading quite a bit of your answers/texts during the last days :-)

Comment: Imho \mainline and \variation which are both skak-based are problematic for complicated automatic printing. skak mixes the parsing and the printing and this makes it very difficult to inject code. Did you try to get the printing with \printchessgame instead?

Comment: No I didn't, but it works now with mainline/variation :-)    (\variation[level=2]{19... }\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{ -- } 20. Qe3 }) is good enough, since variation also takes move numbers only (when I tried that the first time it somehow didn't - maybe I placed the xskakcomment differently)

Comment: just to add if anyone has the same problem:      (\variation[level=2]{1. \xskakcomment{. -- }dxe4 } \variation[level=2]{2. dxe4     is the solution for adding it to a first white move. (\variation does not check if dxe4 is a white move, so it just processes it.)